# Recursion confusion in Haskell again - subsets with an inclusion test

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm testing a simple program to generate subsets with an inclusion test. For example, given

```
*Main Data.List> factorsets 7
[([2],2),([2,3],1),([3],1),([5],1),([7],1)]
```

calling `chooseP 3 (factorsets 7)`, I would like to get (read from right to left, a la `cons`)

```
[[([5],1),([3],1),([2],2)]
,[([7],1),([3],1),([2],2)]
,[([7],1),([5],1),([2],2)]
,[([7],1),([5],1),([2,3],1)]
,[([7],1),([5],1),([3],1)]]
```

But my program is returning an extra `[([7],1),([5],1),([3],1)]` (and missing a 
`[([7],1),([5],1),([2],2)]`):

```
[[([5],1),([3],1),([2],2)]
,[([7],1),([3],1),([2],2)]
,[([7],1),([5],1),([3],1)]
,[([7],1),([5],1),([2,3],1)]
,[([7],1),([5],1),([3],1)]]
```

The inclusion test is: members' first part of the tuple must have a null intersection.

Once tested as working, the plan is to sum the internal products of each subset's `snd`s, rather than accumulate them.

Since I've asked a similar question before, I imagine that an extra branch is generated since when the recursion splits at [2,3], the second branch runs over the same possibilities once it passes the skipped section. Any pointers on how to resolve that would be appreciated; and if you'd like to share ideas about how to enumerate and sum such product combinations more efficiently, that would be great, too.

Haskell code:

```
chooseP k xs = chooseP' xs [] 0 where
  chooseP' [] product count = if count == k then [product] else []
  chooseP' yys product count
    | count == k = [product]
    | null yys   = []
    | otherwise  = f ++ g
   where (y:ys) = yys
         (factorsY,numY) = y
         f = let zzs = dropWhile (\(fs,ns) -> not . and . map (null . intersect fs . fst) $ product) yys
             in if null zzs
                   then chooseP' [] product count
                   else let (z:zs) = zzs in chooseP' zs (z:product) (count + 1)
         g = if and . map (null . intersect factorsY . fst) $ product
                then chooseP' ys product count
                else chooseP' ys [] 0
```

Comment: If you described what this function is supposed to be doing a little bit, it would help me a lot. As it is, since I'm not a compiler, I have a lot of trouble keeping the whole function in my head -- and I wish I were able to chunk it a bit more by matching intent to implementation.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you for your comment. The function is supposed to generate all subsets of length k, without creating duplicates, with the caveat that members' `fst`'s must have a null `intersect`. All `fst`'s and the list is pre-sorted so one would only need to test the last element against the next rather than all members.

Comment: @groovy Subsets of length `k` of _what_ set? What is an `fst`? What's an `snd`?

Comment: @roliu Subsets of the example set (on second/third line): `[([2],2),([2,3],1),([3],1),([5],1),([7],1)]`. `fst` and `snd` meaning first and second elements of the tuples.

Comment: @groovy Sorry I'm confused how you even generated the original set with `factorsets 7`, but if you are only debugging `chooseP` I guess it doesn't matter. Ah I bet `fst` and `snd` actually mean something in haskell which is why that was a dumb question.

Comment: @roliu I'll tell you about `factorsets` when I get `chooseP` working :)

Comment: @groovy In that case, I don't understand the input/output example. e.g. why do you expect `[([7],1),([3],1),([2],2)]` to be there but not `[([7],1),([5],1),([2],2)]`?

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you again...you're right, I missed that...hopefully it's the same bug.

Comment: @groovy I'm a bit confused about the logic behind cases `f` and `g`. I think adding comments about which tuples `f` should generate vs. which ones `g` should generate, and, finally, why those two sets of tuples will be disjoint would be useful. Also your claim about only having to check intersection with `prev` seems incorrect. Consider `([1,3],2), ([2,4],2), ([3],2)`. Am I misinterpreting your claim?

Comment: @roliu `f` and `g` are supposed to lead the recursion in different paths based on if tuples are skipped during subset construction. thanks for pointing that out. I might have to rethink my idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is complicated enough that I might recommend starting over. Here's how I would proceed.

1. Write a specification. Let it be as stupidly inefficient as necessary -- for example, the spec I choose below will build *all* combinations of `k` elements from the list, then filter out the bad ones. Even the filter will be stupidly slow.

   ```
   sorted   xs = sort xs == xs
   unique   xs = nub xs == xs
   disjoint xs = and $ liftM2 go xs xs where
       go x1 x2 = x1 == x2 || null (intersect x1 x2)

   -- check that x is valid according to all the validation functions in fs
   -- (there are other fun ways to spell this, but this is particularly
   -- readable and clearly correct -- just what we want from a spec)
   allFuns fs x = all ($x) fs

   choosePSpec k = filter good . replicateM k where
       good pairs = allFuns [unique, disjoint, sorted] (map fst pairs)
   ```

   Just to make sure it's right, we can test it at the prompt:

   ```
   *Main> mapM_ print $ choosePSpec 3 [([2],2),([2,3],1),([3],1),([5],1),([7],1)]
   [([2],2),([3],1),([5],1)]
   [([2],2),([3],1),([7],1)]
   [([2],2),([5],1),([7],1)]
   [([2,3],1),([5],1),([7],1)]
   [([3],1),([5],1),([7],1)]
   ```

   Looks good.
2. Now that we have a spec, we can try to improve the speed one refactoring at a time, always checking that it matches the spec. The first thing I'd want to do is notice that we can ensure uniqueness and sortedness just by sorting the input and picking things "in an increasing way". To do this, we can define a function which chooses subsequences of a given length. It piggy-backs on the `tails` function, which you can think of as nondeterministically choosing a place to split its input list.

   ```
   subseq 0 xs = [[]]
   subseq n xs = do
       x':xt <- tails xs
       xs'   <- subseq (n-1) xt
       return (x':xs')
   ```

   Here's an example of this function in action:

   ```
   *Main> subseq 3 [1..4]
   [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
   ```

   Now we can write a slightly faster `chooseP` by replacing `replicateM` with `subseq`. Recall that we're assuming the inputs are already sorted and unique, though.

   ```
   choosePSlow k = filter good . subseq k where
       good pairs = disjoint $ map fst pairs
   ```

   We can sanity-check that it's working by running it on the particular input we have from above:

   ```
   *Main> let i = [([2],2),([2,3],1),([3],1),([5],1),([7],1)]
   *Main> choosePSlow 3 i == choosePSpec 3 i
   True
   ```

   Or, better yet, we can stress-test it with QuickCheck. We'll need a tiny bit more code. The condition `k < 5` is just because the spec is so hopelessly slow that bigger values of `k` take forever.

   ```
   propSlowMatchesSpec :: NonNegative Int -> OrderedList ([Int], Int) -> Property
   propSlowMatchesSpec (NonNegative k) (Ordered xs)
       =   k < 5 && unique (map fst xs)
       ==> choosePSlow k xs == choosePSpec k xs

   *Main> quickCheck propSlowMatchesSpec
   +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
   ```
3. There are several more opportunities to make things faster. For instance, the `disjoint` test could be sped up using `choose 2` instead of `liftM2`; or we might be able to ensure disjointness during element selection and prune the search even earlier;  etc. How you want to improve it from here I leave to you -- but the basic technique (start with stupid and slow, then make it smarter, testing as you go) should be helpful to you.